# Word footer social media icons and info

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, icons, text-formatting, footers

Hope everyone is doing good.
I want to add FB and IG icons to the footer of a printed letter with the pages name next to each icon and add a customer service line at the bottom and the website URL. so far i managed to insert the icons but they remain stick to each other and i can't move them apart and when i write next to the logo, i can't make the text appear higher.
[https://i.imgur.com/Bgr7O7w.jpg[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZdmK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The footer in a Word doc allows same formatting as the main body. In this case you can add spaces, tabs, alignment, and the Layout Tools for embedded images.

Show/Hide symbols, the ¶ button or Ctrl+Shift+8, can be helpful for tweaking.
Also, note that images in the header and footer will appear desaturated while working in Word but will appear normal in page preview, when printed or exported to pdf.